# GTK TextView tags to pango markup

Tags: html, gtk, pango

I want to extract the formated text in a GtkTextView as *html* or *pango markup language*.

Having a small text editor with formating like [this](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html). So the formating elements are simple
`<b>`, `<i>`, etc.

Is there a way to get the formated text from the TexView?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gtk_text_buffer_serialize()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-serialize). However, the only built-in serializer is GTK's internal text buffer format, so if you want HTML or Pango markup, you'll have to write the serializing function yourself.

Several years ago I wrote a [GtkTextBuffer serializer for RTF](https://sf.net/p/osxcart). I don't know if it'll help you or inspire you to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

I had the need to convert the content of a Gtk TextBuffer with Pango rich text
markup to HTML, the format that data is stored in, within the
application, similarly to your requirements.

I couldn't find an easy way to do it out of the box, and I ended up
writing my own *converter* from the Gtk serialised content to html.

It uses `html`, which is part of the standard library, and as we already
had `BeautifulSoup4` as a dependency, it leverages it as well.

First, we defined a class derived from `Gtk.TextBuffer` that overwrites
the `get_text` method, that returns the content as text or as HTML when
`include_hidden_chars` is set:

```py
class PangoBuffer(Gtk.TextBuffer):

    def get_text(self,
                  start: Optional[Gtk.TextIter] = None,
                  end: Optional[Gtk.TextIter] = None,
                  include_hidden_chars: bool = False) -> str:
         """Get the buffer content.

         If `include_hidden_chars` is set, then the html markup content is
         returned. If False, then the text only is returned."""
         if start is None:
             start = self.get_start_iter()
         if end is None:
             end = self.get_end_iter()

         if include_hidden_chars is False:
             return super().get_text(start, end, include_hidden_chars=False)
         else:
             format_ = self.register_serialize_tagset()
             content = self.serialize(self, format_, start, end)
             return PangoToHtml().feed(content)
```

The important parts are within the `else` block. I would have preferred
to develop my own serialiser, but the documentation is sparse. We
therefore use the built-in serialiser, resuting in a binary content.

This content is basically XML markup with an extra header and footer:

```xml
# Truncated for legibility.

GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001\x00\x00\x07Z
<text_view_markup>
     <tags>
        <tag id="12" priority="12"> </tag>  # Tags can be empty
        <tag name="italic" priority="2">
            <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />
         </tag>
         <tag id="7" priority="7">
             <attr name="background-gdk" type="GdkColor" value="0:0:ffff" />
             <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />
             <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />
         </tag>
     </tags>
     <text>
         <apply_tag name="italic">This is italic</apply_tag>
         <apply_tag id="1">. </apply_tag>
         <apply_tag id="2">This is italic</apply_tag>
         <apply_tag id="3">\n            </apply_tag>
         <apply_tag id="7">This is bold, italic, and has background colouring.</apply_tag>
     </text>
</text_view_markup>
```

From this, we can establish that tags are not sorted, and they can have
either an `id` or a `name`.

Tags that contain `id` are referred to as *anonymous*, and are typically
created by Pango when deserialising content.

Named tags are typically the ones defined in your application:

```py
tag_bold = TextBuffer.create_tag("bold", weight=Pango.Weight.BOLD)
tag_italic = TextBuffer.create_tag("italic", style=Pango.Style.ITALIC)
tag_underline = TextBuffer.create_tag("underline", underline=Pango.Underline.SINGLE)
```

The header contains a checksum that may not be deserialised when calling
`bytes.decode`, thus it will have to be removed prior to decoding to xml
string.

Then the `PangoToHtml` class does the actual job:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from gi.repository import Pango


class PangoToHtml(HTMLParser):
    """Decode a subset of Pango markup and serialize it as HTML.

    Only the Pango markup used within Gourmet is handled, although expanding it
    is not difficult.

    Due to the way that Pango attributes work, the HTML is not necessarily the
    simplest. For example italic tags may be closed early and reopened if other
    attributes, eg. bold, are inserted mid-way:

        <i> italic text </i><i><u>and underlined</u></i>

    This means that the HTML resulting from the conversion by this object may
    differ from the original that was fed to the caller.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.markup_text: str = ""  # the resulting content
        self.current_opening_tags: str = ""  # used during parsing
        self.current_closing_tags: List = []  # used during parsing

        # The key is the Pango id of a tag, and the value is a tuple of opening
        # and closing html tags for this id.
        self.tags: Dict[str: Tuple[str, str]] = {}

        # Optionally, links can be specified, in a {link text: target} format.
        self.links: Dict[str, str] = {}

        # If links are specified, it is possible to ignore them, as is done with
        # time links.
        self.ignore_links: bool = False

        # Used as heuristics for parsing links, when applicable.
        self.is_colored_and_underlined: bool = False

    tag2html: Dict[str, Tuple[str, str]] = {
        Pango.Style.ITALIC.value_name: ("<i>", "</i>"),  # Pango doesn't do <em>
        str(Pango.Weight.BOLD.real): ("<b>", "</b>"),
        Pango.Underline.SINGLE.value_name: ("<u>", "</u>"),
        "foreground-gdk": (r'<span foreground="{}">', "</span>"),
        "background-gdk": (r'<span background="{}">', "</span>")
    }

    @staticmethod
    def pango_to_html_hex(val: str) -> str:
        """Convert 32 bit Pango color hex string to 16 html.

        Pango string have the format 'ffff:ffff:ffff' (for white).
        These values get truncated to 16 bits per color into a single string:
        '#FFFFFF'.
        """
        red, green, blue = val.split(":")
        red = hex(255 * int(red, base=16) // 65535)[2:].zfill(2)
        green = hex(255 * int(green, base=16) // 65535)[2:].zfill(2)
        blue = hex(255 * int(blue, base=16) // 65535)[2:].zfill(2)
        return f"#{red}{green}{blue}"

    def feed(self, data: bytes) -> str:
        """Convert a buffer (text and and the buffer's iterators to html string.

        Unlike an HTMLParser, the whole string must be passed at once, chunks
        are not supported.

        Optionally, a dictionary of links, in the format {text: target}, can be
        specified. Links will be inserted if some text in the markup will be
        coloured, underlined, and matching an entry in the dictionary.

        If `ignore_links` is set, along with the `links` dictionary, then links
        will be serialized as regular text, and the link targets will be lost.
        """
        # Remove the Pango header: it contains a length mark, which we don't
        # care about, but which does not necessarily decodes as valid char.
        header_end = data.find(b"<text_view_markup>")
        data = data[header_end:].decode()

        # Get the tags
        tags_begin = data.index("<tags>")
        tags_end = data.index("</tags>") + len("</tags>")
        tags = data[tags_begin:tags_end]
        data = data[tags_end:]

        # Get the textual content
        text_begin = data.index("<text>")
        text_end = data.index("</text>") + len("</text>")
        text = data[text_begin:text_end]

        # Convert the tags to html.
        # We know that only a subset of HTML is handled in Gourmet:
        # italics, bold, underlined, normal, and links (coloured & underlined)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(tags, features="lxml")
        tags = soup.find_all("tag")

        tags_list = {}
        for tag in tags:
            opening_tags = ""
            closing_tags = ""

            # The tag may have a name, for named tags, or else an id
            tag_name = tag.attrs.get('id')
            tag_name = tag.attrs.get('name', tag_name)

            attributes = [c for c in tag.contents if isinstance(c, Tag)]
            for attribute in attributes:
                vtype = attribute['type']
                value = attribute['value']
                name = attribute['name']

                if vtype == "GdkColor":  # Convert colours to html
                    if name in ['foreground-gdk', 'background-gdk']:
                        opening, closing = self.tag2html[name]
                        hex_color = self.pango_to_html_hex(value)
                        opening = opening.format(hex_color)
                    else:
                        continue  # no idea!
                else:
                    opening, closing = self.tag2html[value]

                opening_tags += opening
                closing_tags = closing + closing_tags   # closing tags are FILO

            tags_list[tag_name] = opening_tags, closing_tags

            if opening_tags:
                tags_list[tag_name] = opening_tags, closing_tags

        self.tags = tags_list

        # Create a single output string that will be sequentially appended to
        # during feeding of text. It can then be returned once we've parse all
        self.markup_text = ""
        self.current_opening_tags = ""
        self.current_closing_tags = []  # Closing tags are FILO
        self.is_colored_and_underlined = False

        super().feed(text)

        return self.markup_text

    def handle_starttag(self, tag: str, attrs: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> None:
        # The pango tags are either "apply_tag", or "text". We only really care
        # about the "apply_tag". There could be an assert, but we let the
        # parser quietly handle nonsense.
        if tag == "apply_tag":
            attrs = dict(attrs)
            tag_name = attrs.get('id')  # A tag may have a name, or else an id
            tag_name = attrs.get('name', tag_name)
            tags = self.tags.get(tag_name)

            if tags is not None:
                self.current_opening_tags, closing_tag = tags
                self.current_closing_tags.append(closing_tag)

    def handle_data(self, data: str) -> None:
        data = self.current_opening_tags + data
        self.markup_text += data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag: str) -> None:
        if self.current_closing_tags:  # Can be empty due to closing "text" tag
            self.markup_text += self.current_closing_tags.pop()
        self.current_opening_tags = ""
```

As per the
[HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) doc, it
*serves as the basis for parsing text files
formatted in HTML (HyperText Mark-up Language) and XHTML.* We know
that we want to handle start and end tags, and the content in between.

Within the serialised content, tags are referred by their name or id,
which therefore must be processed beforehand.

In this case, I chose to use `BeautifulSoup`, as it offers an easy way
to go through the XML tags in a simple loop.

Could the whole thing have been made with only either `BeautifulSoup` or
the `html` library? Probably yes, but I needed support for all sorts of links, so the [end result](https://github.com/cydanil/gourmet/blob/master/gourmet/gtk_extras/pango_html.py)
differs a bit, as I needed the flexibility that `HTMLParser` offers.

Here's a basic unit test:

```py
from pango_html import PangoToHtml


def test_convert_colors_to_html():
    val = "0:0:0"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#000000"

    val = "ffff:0:0"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#ff0000"

    val = "0:ffff:0"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#00ff00"

    val = "0:0:ffff"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#0000ff"

    val = "ffff:ffff:ffff"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#ffffff"

    val = "0:00000000:ffff"  # add some arbitrary amounts of leading zeroes
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#0000ff"

    val = "ff00:d700:0000"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#fed600"  # Gold

    val = "ffff:1414:9393"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#ff1493"  # Deep Pink

    val = "4747:5f5f:9494"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#475f94"  # Some Blue

    val = "00fd:ffdc:ff5c"
    ret = PangoToHtml.pango_to_html_hex(val)
    assert ret == "#00fefe"  # Some other blue


def test_pango_markup_to_html():
    # These are examples found throughout the application

    pango_markup = b'GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001\x00\x00\x07Z <text_view_markup>\n <tags>\n  <tag id="12" priority="12">\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="2" priority="2">\n   <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="8" priority="8">\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="3" priority="3">\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="7" priority="7">\n   <attr name="background-gdk" type="GdkColor" value="0:0:ffff" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="4" priority="4">\n   <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />\n   <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="5" priority="5">\n   <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />\n   <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />\n   <attr name="underline" type="PangoUnderline" value="PANGO_UNDERLINE_SINGLE" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="0" priority="0">\n   <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="1" priority="1">\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="6" priority="6">\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="9" priority="9">\n   <attr name="foreground-gdk" type="GdkColor" value="0:0:ffff" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="11" priority="11">\n   <attr name="background-gdk" type="GdkColor" value="0:0:ffff" />\n   <attr name="foreground-gdk" type="GdkColor" value="ffff:ffff:ffff" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag id="10" priority="10">\n  </tag>\n </tags>\n<text><apply_tag id="0">This is bold</apply_tag><apply_tag id="1">. </apply_tag><apply_tag id="2">This is italic</apply_tag><apply_tag id="3">\n            </apply_tag><apply_tag id="4">This is bold, italic, and </apply_tag><apply_tag id="5">underlined!</apply_tag><apply_tag id="6">\n            </apply_tag><apply_tag id="7">This is a test of bg color</apply_tag><apply_tag id="8">\n            </apply_tag><apply_tag id="9">This is a test of fg color</apply_tag><apply_tag id="10">\n            </apply_tag><apply_tag id="11">This is a test of fg and bg color</apply_tag><apply_tag id="12">\n           +</apply_tag></text>\n</text_view_markup>\n'  # noqa
    expected = '<b>This is bold</b>. <i>This is italic</i>\n            <i><b>This is bold, italic, and </b></i><i><b><u>underlined!</u></b></i>\n            <span background="#0000ff">This is a test of bg color</span>\n            <span foreground="#0000ff">This is a test of fg color</span>\n            <span background="#0000ff"><span foreground="#ffffff">This is a test of fg and bg color</span></span>\n           +'  # noqa

    ret = PangoToHtml().feed(pango_markup)
    assert ret == expected

    pango_markup = b'GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001\x00\x00\x01i <text_view_markup>\n <tags>\n  <tag name="italic" priority="1">\n   <attr name="style" type="PangoStyle" value="PANGO_STYLE_ITALIC" />\n  </tag>\n  <tag name="bold" priority="0">\n   <attr name="weight" type="gint" value="700" />\n  </tag>\n </tags>\n<text>ddf<apply_tag name="bold">fd<apply_tag name="italic">df</apply_tag>fd</apply_tag>dff</text>\n</text_view_markup>\n'  # noqa
    expected = 'ddf<b>fd<i>df</i>fd</b>dff'

    ret = PangoToHtml().feed(pango_markup)
    assert ret == expected
```